# Treemap in Kibana

Tags: kibana-5

Is it possible to create a treemap in Kibana? Treemap is not among the visualizations types shown in the visualize tap. I am using Kibana 5.5. Is there a plugin out there?[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in Kibana asking for this (you might want to go in and give it a thumbs up to increase the chances of it being prioritized):
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/11790

There is also a non-official visualization created by bgeVam: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/bgevam-kibana-treemap-visualization/165892